# How my web crawler(python, Scrapy, Scrapy-splash) can crawl faster?

Tags: mongodb, scrapy, web-crawler, python-3.7, scrapy-splash

**Develop Environment:**

- CentOS7
- pip 18.1
- Docker version 18.09.3, build 774a1f4
- anaconda Command line client (version 1.7.2)
- Python3.7
- Scrapy 1.6.0
- scrapy-splash
- MongoDB(db version v4.0.6)
- PyCharm

**Server Specs:**

- CPU ->
  processor: 22, 
  vendor_id: GenuineIntel, 
  cpu family: 6, 
  model: 45, 
  model name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2430 0 @ 2.20GHz
- RAM -> Mem: 31960
- 64 bit

Hello.

I'm a php developer, and this is my first python project. I'm trying to use python because I heard that python has many benefits for web crawling.

I'm crawling one dynamic web site, and I need to crawl around 3,500 pages in every 5-15 seconds. For now, mine is too slow. It is crawl only 200 pages per minute.

My source is like this:

## main.py

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from spiders.bot1 import Bot1Spider
from spiders.bot2 import Bot2Spider
from spiders.bot3 import Bot3Spider
from spiders.bot4 import Bot4Spider
from pprint import pprint


process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
process.crawl(Oddsbot1Spider)
process.crawl(Oddsbot2Spider)
process.crawl(Oddsbot3Spider)
process.crawl(Oddsbot4Spider)
process.start()
```

## bot1.py

```
import scrapy
import datetime
import math

from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pprint import pprint


class Bot1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'bot1'
    client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
    db = client.db

    def start_requests(self):
        count = int(self.db.games.find().count())
        num = math.floor(count*0.25)
        start_urls = self.db.games.find().limit(num-1)

        for url in start_urls:
            full_url = domain + list(url.values())[5]
            yield SplashRequest(full_url, self.parse, args={'wait': 0.1}, meta={'oid': list(url.values())[0]})

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

## settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'crawler'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['crawler.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'crawler.spiders'


# Scrapy Configuration

SPLASH_URL = 'http://localhost:8050'

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}

SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}

DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
USER_AGENT = 'my-project-name (www.my.domain)'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 64

# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
#DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 16
```

When execute these code, I'm using this command: **python main.py**

After seeing my code, please help me. I'll happily listen any saying.

**1.How my spider can faster?** I've tried to use threading, but it's seem not working right.

**2.What is the best performance line up for web crawling?**

**3.Is that possible to crawl 3500 dynamic pages in every 5-15 seconds?**

Thank you.

Comment: Run the Scrapy benchmark to see the best case scenario on your hardware ([docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/benchmarking.html)). But keep in mind a Splash request will be slower.

Comment: One possible area you can investigate is whether the website has an API you can use instead of Splash. That should already speed things up.

Comment: Also, add your `settings.py` so we can see your `CONCURRENT_*` and `AUTOTHROTTLE_*` settings.

Comment: If all these pages belong to the one website, then it is a small DDOS attack (~14k - 42k requests per minute)

Comment: @malberts Thank you for response. (1) I think I'm going to use 'scrapy benchmark' very useful. (2) I think I already tried API way. I sent ajax with jsonp type and data was response with callback, but after 1 hour, it denied. (3) I uploaded it! Thanks again!

Comment: @Neodan I though about it, too. Is that illegal?I don't know well about moral(or right) for crawling . If you know some sites or pages for this, please share it. Thank you!